# how to grep last occurrence of special character using perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
Tag: /tags/abc_d
 Tag: /tags/xyz
```

This is my input file. I have to grep second "/" and remaining word into array?
How can I finished this using perl regex.
Am newer to perl so Could u help me??

Answer (score 0):

If $_ has the line in then this

```
my ($p) = (/\/([^\/]+)$/);
```

will make $p contain the last part of the path. It matches a / then any number of non / chars to the end of the line. The inner parentheses captures the result.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I tried this code but it give only 111111111 like this

Answer (score 0):

If there is more stuff in your input data and you need to make sure only to get the ones with *Tag* in the beginning, you can use this regex:

```
/^\s*Tag.+?\/(\w+)$/
```

Try it out on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sO5eA4).